# SVN - how to revert to oldest version

Tags: svn, repository

After checking out a repository, I want to revert it to the oldest version. Is there a way to do it? Anything short of running

```
svn log | grep '|' > log
```

(I have to do this for multiple folders). And then getting the first word of the last line and then removing the 'r' and then converting it to an integer. And this assumes that no commit messages have '|' in them, which I guess is a safe assumption,  but isn't "correct", as such.

Note: I know how to check out out a specific revision number.

Running `svn revert ./*` within the directory didn't work either. After doing that, when I ran `svn up`, it said "At revision __" (latest revision). Running `svn co -r` works fine

Comment: I am confused.  Why can't you just checkout a specific version number?

Comment: I can. But I need to do this for around 19 folders, so I'd have to run 'svn log', wait for the result, then find the last number, and then checkout that revision. `revert` seems to be what I'm looking for, but it isn't working, for some reason

Comment: @asymptotically: `revert` actually undoes local changes made to the working: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html

Comment: So if I checkout the lastest revision and `revert`, it doesn't do anything? Oh ...

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. The first, is "how do I quickly find the first revision for a directory in the repository". This can probably be solved as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675749/how-do-i-see-the-last-10-commits-in-reverse-chronoligical-order-with-svn using `svn log --limit 1 -r1:HEAD` which should limit you to the earliest single log message for the directory. This uses "--limit 1" to show only a single message, and "-r1:HEAD" to order the displayed messages from first to last instead of the usual last to first.

The second problem, is "how do I get my working copy to point to a specific revision, once I know the revision?"

As you know, `svn co -r123` will get you a NEW working copy at revision 123. If you already have a working copy, you just use `svn update -r123` instead, to update your working copy to that revision.

Note that you can also use dates in your revision specifier, as detailed at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates . Also a few keywords are supported like HEAD.

Comment: I still have to parse the output of `svn log` in order to get the revision number, and then run `svn update` or `svn co` with it. I was wondering if there was a simpler way to directly get the revision number without having to parse anything, because it seems like something that could be common.

Comment: I don't think so. But you can use a date without knowing a revision number, if you know a date which would correspond to the revision you want.